# How does Java colorspace affect displayed pixels?

Tags: java, macos, swing, colors

My Java program displays a Color created with RGB values 0 104 217. When I examine the display on my iMac using Digital Color Meter it reports the native values as 0 104 217 and the sRGB values as 0 (clipped) 99 220. I thought sRGB was the default color space in Java and expected the sRGB values to match the values in my Color. Instead, the native values match. What am I missing?

The program:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test
    extends JFrame
{
    public Test()
    {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setBackground(new Color(0, 104, 217));
        setContentPane(p);
        setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Not surprisingly, the profile is iMac. But why should this matter?

Comment: I would expect the native and sRGB values to be the same, as reported by Digital Color Meter. This does not solve my problem, which is to create a known color in Java for an arbitrary color managed display.